# Pandas Mulmtiindex Mutiply columns level 1

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have the following sample data set :
[image]

with this code I managed to load it in a pandas dataframe and do basic manipulation like having the total number of days per profile and total cost.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('multiindex.xlsx', "0001",header=[0,1,2,3],index_col=[0,1,2])

print(df)

print(df.axes[1])

print(df.axes[0])
df['Total days'] = df.groupby(axis = 1,level = 'Full project').sum()
df['Total cost']=(df.index.get_level_values('Daily rate')*df['Total days']).values
print (df)
```

Now I want to add a "Total cost" for each phase, I can create the aggregated df with the following code

```
df2 = df.groupby(axis = 1,level = 'Phase').sum()
print( df2 )



Phase                           Build  Discovery
   Profile Name Daily rate                         
   Dev     dev1 10          110.0    4.0        6.0
           dev2 10           88.0    4.0        4.0
           dev3 10           88.0    4.0        4.0
   QA      qa1  10          110.0    4.0        6.0
           qa2  10           88.0    4.0        4.0
```

But how can I multiply "Daily rates" by each sub-columns in Phase and add a column named "[phase name] total cost" without having to specify each phase name, and get a result like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) for multiple all columns, then use [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and append to original DataFrame `df2`:

```
df2 = df.sum(axis = 1,level = 'Phase')

df22 = df2.mul(df2.index.get_level_values('Daily rate'), axis=0).add_prefix(' total cost')
df2 = df2.join(df22)
```